# How to split a longer formula into multiple lines with PHP?

Tags: php, math, syntax, calc

I have to do some more complicated formulas with PHP. It would be cool if I could split the formula into multiple lines. I know how to do that with strings, but I have no idea how to do it within one single calculation.

i want to do something like:

```
public function example_calc(){
  $result = $var1 * $var2 +
    + $var3 * $var4 -
    - $var5 / $var6;
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't duplicate `+` and `-` signs across lines, just split it normally

```
public function example_calc(){
  $result = $var1 * $var2
    + $var3 * $var4
    - $var5 / $var6;
  return $result;
}
```

or

```
public function example_calc(){
  $result = $var1 * $var2 +
    $var3 * $var4 -
    $var5 / $var6;
  return $result;
}
```

and the really cool will just work

It's the `;` that marks the end of the "line" of code, not the carriage return/line feed

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mark Baker's observation that you shouldn't double your `+` and `-`, you can always create temporary variables:

```
public function example_calc(){
  $prod1 = $var1 * $var2;
  $prod2 = $var3 * $var4;
  $quot = $var5 / $var6;
  $result = $prod1 + $prod2 - $quot;
  return $result;
}
```